# How to dispaly ancestors on ancestry gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

I tried to follow the rails cast tutorials on using the ancestry gem but I had in these issues. I can display the ancestor id on the index or show page. The ancestor id is blank when I go to the edit page. What am I not doing correctly. am new to rails

```
#page.rb 

class Page < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :parent_id 
  has_ancestry
end


#_form.html.erb

<%= f.label :parent_id %>
<%= f.collection_select :parent_id, Page.order(:name), :id,:name, include_blank: true %>
```

```
#index.html.erb

 <% @pages.each do |page| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= page.name %></td>
    <td><%= page.content %></td>
    <td><%= page.parent_id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', page %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_page_path(page) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', page, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr> 
<% end %>
```